# POOTIS POW! But what is Pootis?

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology, tf2-heavy

I always hear the word 'pootis' when someone is heavy.  I know Heavy is of russian background, but is pootis even a real word?  What is pootis supposed to mean?

It's so dang fun to say I would like to know the actual meaning of the word, if there is one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[“Pootis” comes from the phrase “Put dispenser here” said by the Heavy in TF2 which is used as a voice command.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/pootis)

Comment: This is it. The way Heavy says "Put dispenser here" sounds like "Pootis penser here"

Comment: Ahaha so that's where it comes from! Thanks, good to know!